# Function of the trajectory of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that there is no continuously differentiable non-constant function $H : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla H(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ so that for every solution of the differential equation $\dot x = -x , \dot y = -2y :$ $H(x(t),y(t)) = c, c \in \mathbb{R}$ holds.

The solution of the differential equation is $x(t) = e^{-t}, y(t) = e^{-2t}$, then if $H$ is such a function: $d/dt H(e^{-t}, e^{-2t}) = -\partial_xH(e^{-t}, e^{-2t})e^{-t} -\partial_yH(e^{-t}, e^{-2t})2e^{-2t} = 0 $ for all $ t \in \mathbb{R} $.
So we have $-\partial_yH(e^{-t}, e^{-2t})2e^{-t} = \partial_xH(e^{-t}, e^{-2t})$ and for $t \to \infty: \partial_xH(0,0) = 0 $ which is a contradicition to $\nabla H(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The solutions are not just "$x(t) = e^{-t}, y(t) = e^{-2t}$": they are $$x(t) =  e^{-t}x_0, \quad y(t) = e^{-2t}y_0$$
2. Demonstrating $\partial_x H(0,0)=0$ (which you've done correctly) is not a contradiction to $\nabla H(0,0)\ne 0$, since the gradient vector also has a $y$-component.

A better  approach is this. All solution curves approach $(0,0)$. So, by continuity, $H$ must be equal to $H(0,0)$ on every solution curve. Therefore, $H$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't get why $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\ H(e^{-t}x_0, e^{-2t}y_0 = H(0,0)$ means that $H(x,y) = H(0,0)$ for all $x,y$. Also why is my solution not correct? $\nabla H(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ means that $\partial_xH(x,y) \neq 0$ and $\partial_y H(x,y) \neq 0$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You assume that $H$ is constant on every trajectory. The trajectory approaches $(0,0)$, so the constant has to be $H(0,0)$. And the whole plane is covered by trajectories (there's one through every point).

Comment: For your second part: please review what it means for two vector to be equal or not equal.

Comment: Embarrassing: "or" instead of "and". Why can I assume $H$ is constant, that's what I want to prove?

Comment: In your post it is assumed that $H$ is constant on every solution curve.

Comment: Ah thanks, I get it now. Still, why is my solution wrong, as you corrected, only one of the components of the gradient of $H$ needs to be zero for it to be a contradiction.